# 'Cannot read property 'DV' of undefined' when reading information from state of component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Undefined error when trying to read information from a JSON object in 'this.state'.

Component Class:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {}
    // Code is invoked after the component is mounted/inserted into the DOM tree.
    componentDidMount() {
      const url = 'http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/json/APIKEY'

      fetch(url)
        .then(response => {return response.json()})
        .then(data => {
          this.setState(data)
        })      
    }

    render() {
      console.log(this.state.SiteRep.DV)

      return <p>TEXT</p>
    }
  }

  export default App
```

Json Object:

```
{
  "SiteRep": {
    "Wx": {
      "Param": [
        {
          "name": "FDm",
          "units": "C",
          "$": "Feels Like Day Maximum Temperature"
        },
        {
          "name": "FNm",
          "units": "C",
          "$": "Feels Like Night Minimum Temperature"
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    "DV": {
      "dataDate": "2019-10-09T13:00:00Z",
      "type": "Forecast",
      "Location": {
        "i": "354287",
        "lat": "52.0951",
        "lon": "1.3143",
        "name": "WOODBRIDGE",
        "Period": [
          {
            "type": "Day",
            "value": "2019-10-09Z",
            "Rep": [
              {
                "D": "W",
                "Gn": "22",
                "Hn": "66",
                "PPd": "8",
                ...
              },
              {
                "D": "WSW",
                "Gm": "22",
                "Hm": "87",
                "PPn": "1"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "Day",
            "value": "2019-10-10Z",
            "Rep": [
              {
                "D": "WSW",
                "Gn": "29",
                "Hn": "61",
                "PPd": "5",
              },
              {
                "D": "SW",
                "Gm": "34",
                "Hm": "87",
                "PPn": "19",
              }
            ]
          }
        ...
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am going to map the "Period" list to map some elements, however when trying to access said part of the Object in 'this.state', I am greeted with the error *'Cannot read property 'DV' of undefined'*

The object is found within state, all the Json data is correct and I can access it in Console when I am not beyond the '.SiteRep' object. Feel like I am doing something very wrong :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a lifecycle issue. `ComponentDidMount` triggers after the component has loaded, which means `this.state.SiteRep.DV` does not exist yet. You'll need to add a check to see if `SitRep` exists on `state` so it doesn't error out.
So...

```
if(this.state.hasOwnProperty('SiteRep') console.log(this.state.SiteRep.DV)
```

Here's the expected behavior of the component:

```
First render happens 
=> `ComponentDidMount` is fired 
=> Request is made and response is set to state 
=> setState triggers another render where SiteRep does exist on state
```

Then for your JSX:

```
render() {
 if(this.state.SiteRep && this.state.SiteRep.DV) { 
     return <p>interpolate a value from {this.state.SiteRep.DV.someStringProp} </p>
 }
 return null
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Learning fast :D

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is, although you get your Json in `componentDidMount`, `render()` happens before fetch is completed. Just by checking whether data is available before accessing it would solve your issue.

```
class App extends Component {
      state = {}
        // Code is invoked after the component is mounted/inserted into the DOM tree.
        componentDidMount() {
          const url = 'http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/json/APIKEY'

          fetch(url)
            .then(response => {return response.json()})
            .then(data => {
              this.setState(data)
            })      
        }

        render() {
          if(this.state.SiteRep){
              console.log(this.state.SiteRep.DV);
          }

          return <p>TEXT</p>
        }
      }

      export default App
```

Comment: Awesome that makes sense! Working now, thank you very much.

Comment: Great! Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

> Please consider going through React's Component lifecycle one more time [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle).

This is what's happening in your code:

1. Your component state is initialized to empty object.
2. Component's  `render()`  method is called (where you don't have the data you need).
3. Lifecycle method `componentDidMount()` is called after initial `render()`, where you make an API call and update the state with response data.

**One way to solve this -**

1. You can consider having a flag `isFetching` in your state which is set to `true` initially.

```js
state = { isFetching: true };
```

2. Update your `render()` method to display a fallback UI until your API call is successful i.e. `isFetching` is false;

```js
...

render() {
   const { isFetching } = this.state;
   if (isFetching) {
       return <span> Fetching data </span>;
   }

   console.log(this.state.SiteRep.DV)

   return <p>TEXT</p>
}
...
```

3. Add changes to update your `isFetching` flag when API call is being made:

```js
...
componentDidMount() {
       // You're going to call the API now, set isFetching to true
      this.setState({ isFetching: true });

      const url = 'http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/val/wxfcs/all/json/APIKEY'

      fetch(url)
        .then(response => {return response.json()})
        .then(data => {
          // API call done, set data and make isFetching false.
          this.setState({ data, isFetching: false });
        })      
    }
...
```

**Another approach** would be to add the initial state such as:

```js
state = {
    SiteRep: {
      DV: {}
    }
}
```

> With this approach, initially you would see no data but once API response is updated in your component state, component will re-render.

Personally I'd take the first approach as you can have finer control over your `render()`

Comment: Awesome thank you, the page you linked is especially helpful! Provides a lot of the understanding I was missing.